# Moving boot drive from /dev/sda (regular HD drive) to /dev/sdb( SSD)

Tags: boot, ssd

I believe I messed up during the installation and Ubuntu was installed on my hard drive (I wanted to install it on SSD)

I have been using the system for around 2 months now but the system is a bit slow compared to my expectations ( windows was faster running on the ssd)
So, I checked what the boot drive and it turns out that the boot drive is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       669G   18G  617G   3% /
```

I would like to change it to /dev/sdb (SSD capacity 256 GB) without losing the data and the current application settings. 
Can someone please let me know what are my options.

TIA !

Comment: Do a fresh install on the ssd.

Answer (score 0):

If you have absolutely nothing to save, or if you want a quick solution and you can just backup your files and restore them, then follow the advice of others and do a fresh install.  Continue reading to help understand a bit more about the normal setup, and benefits, etc.

Otherwise,

The 'boot drive', in Linux, is actually `/boot/`, not `/`.  The root of the system, or system root is `/`, which is mapped to a specific partition.  The boot partition stores the boot-level kernel (`initramfs`/`initcpio`), which loads additional modules and functionality from the Linux Kernel that is loaded.

So, when you install your Linux system, you will have `/` and `/boot`.  They do not *have* to be different partitions (with `/boot` having a lower ID, typically), but we typically break them out and have `/boot` as a more simple filesystem, such as `fat32`, and `/` (system root) as a newer filesystem, such as `ext4`.

You should be able to see this by looking at the contents of `/etc/fstab`, or issuing the `mount` command, with no arguments, to show you the currently mounted filesystems.

Yes, in order to have the fastest boot time, you can place the `/boot` partition on the SSD, but in reality, only boot time will increase, not overall performance.  By leaving the `/boot` partition as-is, you can simplify the steps required, or you can choose to move it at higher risk/complication.

By having your `/` (system root) on the SSD, your entire system will speed up, and might be your primary objective and concern.  This is controlled through [kernel parameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters), and would be the only adjustment needed if you maintain the `/boot` partition as-is.

As your system matures, you may even create partitions on the HDD, and mount them on the Linux system (such as `/mnt/data`) so that you can use lower-cost, slower storage for files that are accessed less frequently.

Again, you'll need to carefully inspect the Windows disk and properly shrink the Windows partition so that the disk has additional space for your `/boot` and `/`.  `/boot` doesn't need to be more than 512MB, while `/` size will limit your Linux installation total size, unless you add additional partitions as described above.

`gparted` is available on Ubuntu LiveCD and helps in these processes.

If you boot into Ubuntu using the installation disk, called LiveCD, you can make adjustments to your partitions as descibed.

---

A hybrid approach would be to install Ubuntu onto the SSD, being careful to not destroy any data/partitions, and then mount the existing partition onto the new system after installation.  For example, after installing Ubuntu onto the SSD, you can mount the old Linux partition, and copy files over as needed, or re-use as the previously discussed `/mnt/data` partition for extra space.